# Mapping Types Recursively with an Irregularly Nested Type

Tags: typescript, types, type-mapping

I'm trying to map a theme of mine into a theme object of forms, something like this:

```
type Color1 = string & { __brand: "color1" }
type Color2 = string & { __brand: "color2" }

interface Theme {
  colors: {
    primary: Color1;
  };
  border: {
    radius: number;
  };
  fonts: {
    main: string;
  };
  components: {
    container: {
      padding: number
    },
    radioCheckbox: {
      active: Color1;
    };
  };
}
```

which should be transformed to

```
interface ThemeForm {
  colors: {
    primary: FormField<Color2>;
  };
  border: {
    radius: FormField<number>;
  };
  fonts: {
    main: FormField<boolean>;
  };
  components: {
    container: {
      padding: FormField<number>
    },
    radioCheckbox: {
      active: FormField<Color2>;
    };
  };
}
```

where

```
type FormTypes = string | number | boolean | undefined;

interface FormField<F extends FormTypes> {
  value: F;
  error: boolean;
  errorMsg: string;
}
```

If my `Theme` interface were flatter, I know the solution would look something like this:

```
interface FlatterTheme {
  radius: number;
  padding: number;
  ...
};

type FlatterFormTheme = {
  [K in keyof FlatterTheme]: FormField<FlatterTheme[K]>
}
```

However, my `Theme` interface is unfortunately is nested and with different depth levels, so mapping that type is a bit beyond me. Does anyone know how to do it, or if it really is possible to do in TS?

Comment: Are you trying the wrap all properties with `FormField`?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgv2BW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: In this case, yes, I think so. But I don't know if this could be further generalized into mapping types. For example, instead of only wrapping with `FormField`, also mapping `Color` -> `Color2`, etc.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro who are you replying to?  And if you have some other use case you care about, please [edit] the question to show it so that it's a [mre].

Comment: I was talking to you, jcalz. Your seems seems good enough, I'll take it. But if you could also create one in which you show how to not only do the wrapping but also the mapping of, say, `Color` -> `number` and `string` -> `boolean`, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: That is currently impossible because `Color` is just an alias of `string`; TypeScript can't tell them apart... if you want to see that, could you [edit] the question to change `Color` to some type that differs structurally from `string`, and then put your expected result in the question by modifying `ThemeForm` accordingly?

Comment: Ok, cool. I've added a new section to the question with what I had in mind.

Comment: I was thinking you'd edit the existing question rather than expanding the scope to be multiple questions.  As it is now, the question could be closed as not being focused enough.  Could you please have a single well-defined question?

Comment: The last section was actually what I had in mind from the start, it didn't cross my mind at first that my question could be solved with the more specific wrapping types approach you had proposed. Like I said, if you want to stick to only that wrapping, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I'm happy to answer either one (see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NnEOow)) once the post is edited [to be a single question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts)

Comment: Well, the last section of the question comprises everything that came before, wrapping + type mapping. Is it ok to consider that to be the real *question* then?

Comment:  I'm not sure why you're pushing back on this.  If you'd rather, I could [edit] the question so that instead of being multiple sections that build up to your final version of the question, it just asks the final question first.  I was hoping you would do that so I could work on the answer, but if you're not willing to do that I could.

Comment: It's not that I'm not willing to do it, it's just that I failed to understand what you had in mind, and why what's already there isn't ok already. But it's ok if you edit it. Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: Okay I modified the question, hope it's reasonably close to what you're looking for.  I wasn't sure what you wanted to do with `number`, so I left it alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a `ToForm<T>` utility type to transform `Theme` to `ThemForm` like this:

```
type ToForm<T> =
  T extends Color1 ? FormField<Color2> :
  T extends string ? FormField<boolean> :
  T extends FormTypes ? FormField<T> :
  { [K in keyof T]: ToForm<T[K]> }
```

This is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that maps:

- `Color1` to `FormField<Color2>`,
- a `string` that isn't a `Color1` to `FormField<boolean>`,
- any other `FormTypes` `T` that isn't a `string` to `FormField<T>` (so `number` becomes `FormField<number>`), and crucially:
- any other type (like an object type) to a recursive [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where each property has `ToForm` applied to it.

Note that the order of the clauses is important here because your various cases aren't mutually exclusive.  For example, if they were flipped around like `T extends string ? FormField<boolean> : T extends Color1 ? FormField<Color2> : ⋯` then it would do the wrong thing because `Color1 extends string`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
type ThemeForm = ToForm<Theme>

/*
type ThemeForm = {
    colors: {
        primary: FormField<Color2>;
    };
    border: {
        radius: FormField<number>;
    };
    fonts: {
        main: FormField<boolean>;
    };
    components: {
        container: {
            padding: FormField<number>;
        };
        radioCheckbox: {
            active: FormField<Color2>;
        };
    };
}
*/
```

Looks good; it matches the desired `ThemeForm` from the question.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#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-PYeAOY5TyAkdsWNcdJx7SCpyuURa2rIA)